# Good (standard) way to define and use notations for vectors, r.v., vector of r.v.s etc?

Tags: research

My question is what the conventions are to show scalar, vectors, matrices, random variables, vector, and matrix of random variables? I think some of them are defined as follows:

scalar: Lower-case letters

Random variable: Upper-case letters

Vector: Bold and lower-case letters. The realization of a random variable is denoted by lower-case letters.

Matrix: Bold and upper-case letters

However, I don't know how to show a vector and a matrix of random variables. I am wondering what form of notations is more common in OR/MS? Is there any other case that I have missed? This question might be a matter of personal preference, but I would be thankful to know the most commonly used forms.

Comment: This is definitely a matter of personal preference. Adding to what you have listed, some people put an arrow over a symbol to denote a vector (for instance, $\vec{x}$). All I can suggest is that you (a) be consistent within any one document and (b) explain your notation up front.

Comment: @Amin, see: https://mlpr.inf.ed.ac.uk/2022/notes/w0h_notation.html https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~10601-f20/10601_Notation_Guide.pdf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_calculus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus - there are both preferences and some standard conventions, frequently the format used is explained at the start of a paper.

Answer (score 1):

For vector/matrix of r.v. I have seen notations like $\omega $ for matrix and $ \Omega$ indicating vectors. Other than that this guide from [Carnegie Mellon](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7E10601-f20/10601_Notation_Guide.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiY7ai5iIf9AhV6lYkEHauqBAcQFnoECCUQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3OkrQGZ4cOHpcCiM6RDFEk) may be helpful.